# jQuery opacity slow fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a screen div overlay on top of a supersized banner set. From the start the overlay needs to be set to `0.5` opacity, then when the user starts scrolling over a period of about `300px` scroll it fade gently to `0.9` opacity then stops at that, if the user scrolls back up to less than `300px` from top then it starts to fade slowly back to `0.5` opacity. I'm just using a background color on the div for this.

I'm a little stuck though. I have the below so far but as you start scrolling it goes to `0` opacity then starts from that and fade to `0.9`, then at `300px` it goes to `1` opacity then after `301px` if jumps back to `0.9` opacity.

```
$(function () {
    divFade = $(".fadeScreen");
    var toggleHeader = function (noAnimate) {

        var threshold  = 1,
            fadeLength = 300,
            opacity,
            scrollTop  = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop < threshold) {
            opacity = 0.5;
        } else if (scrollTop > threshold + fadeLength) {
            opacity = 0.9;
        } else {
            if (noAnimate) {
                opacity = 0.9;
            } else {
                opacity = (scrollTop - threshold) / fadeLength;
            }
        }
        divFade.css("opacity", opacity);
    };

    toggleHeader(true);
    $(window).scroll(function () {toggleHeader();});
});
```

I just need it so when the page is loaded the opacity is `0.5`, between `0-300px` scrolling it changes slowly to `0.9` and stays, then when scrolling back up it fades back to `0.5` opacity.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
$(function() {
  divFade = $(".fadeScreen");
  var toggleHeader = function(noAnimate) {

    var threshold = 1,
      fadeLength = 300,
      minOpacity = 0.5,
      maxOpacity = 0.9,
      opacity = minOpacity,
      opacityDiff = (maxOpacity - minOpacity),
      scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop < fadeLength) {
      opacity += (scrollTop / fadeLength) * opacityDiff;
    } else {
      opacity = maxOpacity;
    }
    console.log(scrollTop);
    divFade.css("opacity", opacity);
  };

  toggleHeader(true);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    toggleHeader();
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much, it works perfectly. Now time to look over what your doing so I can start to understand. 

Thank you thank you :)